# Error en matplotlib al graficar ecuaciones de una variable

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

Hola estoy intentando hacer un programa que resuelva ejercicios de programación lineal y grafique con matplotlib los puntos de las restricciones y el punto optimo el algunos ejercicios me grafica normalmente como en este.

```
Max z = 15x1 + 10x2
restricciones
1/3x1 + 1/2x2 <= 100
1/3x1 + 1/6x2 <= 80
x1,x2 >= 0
```

en ejercicios como ese me grafica normalmente pero cuando hay algún ejercicio que solo tiene 1 punto para grafica sea el x1 o x2 y el otro valor es 0 me da un error ya que primero no me marca los puntos de intercepción.

como en este ejemplo

```
Min z = 10x1 + 30x2
restricciones
x1 + 5x2 >= 15
5x1 + x2 >= 15
x1,x2 >= 0
```

Otra duda que tengo es como puedo hacer para que la grafica se ajuste automáticamente dependiendo del ejercicio que le de porque en algunos ejercicio me grafica pero la grafica aveces grande y aveces pequeña hay alguna librería que ajuste la grafica automáticamente?

Saben porque me da ese error y como solucionarlo?
este es mi codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import OptionMenu, StringVar, messagebox
from pulp import *
from fractions import Fraction
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def solve_lp_problem():
    if optionstr.get() == "Max":
        variable_lp = LpMaximize
    elif optionstr.get() == "Min":
        variable_lp = LpMinimize
        
    prob = LpProblem("Problema de Programación Lineal", variable_lp)

    # Crear variables para la función objetivo
    variables = [LpVariable(f'x{i}', lowBound=0) for i in range(num_variables)]

    # Definir la función objetivo
    prob += lpSum([Fraction(obj_coefficients[i].get()) * variables[i] for i in range(num_variables)])

    # Obtener las restricciones
    for i in range(num_constraints):
        constraint_coeffs = [Fraction(cons_coefficients[i][j].get()) for j in range(num_variables)]
        variable_index = constraint_variables[i].get()
        constraint_type = constraint_types[i].get()
        constraint_value = Fraction(cons_values[i].get())

        if constraint_type == "<=":
            prob += lpSum([constraint_coeffs[j] * variables[j] for j in range(num_variables)]) <= constraint_value
        elif constraint_type == ">=":
            prob += lpSum([constraint_coeffs[j] * variables[j] for j in range(num_variables)]) >= constraint_value
        elif constraint_type == "=":
            prob += lpSum([constraint_coeffs[j] * variables[j] for j in range(num_variables)]) == constraint_value

    # Resolver el problema
    prob.solve()
    status = prob.status


    if status == 1:  # Verificar si la solución es óptima
        optimal_value = value(prob.objective)
        messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", f"Estado: Óptimo\n\nValor óptimo: {optimal_value}")

        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

        # Define la gráfica
        x_vals = np.linspace(0, 400, 100)  # Rango y resolución ajustables según sea necesario
        intersection_points = []

        for i in range(num_constraints):
            # Genera las restricciones gráficas
            if constraint_types[i].get() == '<=':
                c0 = Fraction(cons_coefficients[i][0].get())
                c1 = Fraction(cons_coefficients[i][1].get())

                if c1 != 0:
                    y_vals = (float(cons_values[i].get()) - c0 * x_vals) / c1
                    plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, label=f'Restricción {i+1}')  # Grafica la restricción
                else:
                    # Si c1 es cero, graficar una línea vertical en x = valor de la restricción / c0
                    x_val = float(cons_values[i].get()) / c0 if c0 != 0 else 0
                    plt.axvline(x=x_val, label=f'Restricción {i+1}', linestyle='--')  # Línea vertical

                # Encuentra intersecciones con los ejes x e y
                x_intercept = float(cons_values[i].get()) / c0 if c0 != 0 else 0
                y_intercept = float(cons_values[i].get()) / c1 if c1 != 0 else 0

                intersection_points.append((x_intercept, 0))  # Punto de intersección con eje x
                intersection_points.append((0, y_intercept))  # Punto de intersección con eje y

        # Graficar los puntos de intersección
        x, y = zip(*intersection_points)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label='Puntos de Intersección')

        # Obtener el punto óptimo
        opt_x = value(variables[0])
        opt_y = value(variables[1])

        # Graficar el punto óptimo y etiquetarlo
        plt.plot(opt_x, opt_y, 'bo', label='Punto Óptimo')
        plt.text(opt_x, opt_y, f'P.O\n({opt_x:.2f}, {opt_y:.2f})', ha='left')

        # Agregar etiquetas a los puntos de intersección
        for i, (x_val, y_val) in enumerate(intersection_points):
            plt.text(x_val, y_val, f'({x_val:.2f}, {y_val:.2f})', ha='left')

        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('y')
        plt.title('Gráfica de la Función Objetivo y Restricciones')
        plt.grid()
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()  # Muestra la gráfica
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Resultado", "No se encontró una solución óptima.")
            
def add_constraint():
    global num_constraints
    cons_coefficients.append([])
    constraint_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    constraint_frame.pack()

    for i in range(num_variables):
        tk.Label(constraint_frame, text="X" + str(i + 1)).grid(row=num_constraints, column=i)
        
        entry = tk.Entry(constraint_frame, justify='center')  # Crear un Entry con texto centrado
        entry.grid(row=num_constraints+1, column=i)
        
        cons_coefficients[num_constraints].append(entry)

    constraint_variables.append(tk.StringVar(root))
    variable_options = [f'x{i}' for i in range(num_variables)]

    constraint_types.append(tk.StringVar(root))
    tk.OptionMenu(constraint_frame, constraint_types[num_constraints], "<=", ">=", "=").grid(row=num_constraints+1, column=num_variables+2)

    cons_values.append(tk.Entry(constraint_frame, justify='center'))  # Crear un Entry con texto centrado
    cons_values[num_constraints].grid(row=num_constraints+1, column=num_variables+3)

    num_constraints += 1

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Resolución de Programación Lineal")

options = ["Max","Min"]
optionstr = StringVar()
optionstr.set(options[0])

opc_menu = OptionMenu(root, optionstr, *options)
opc_menu.pack(side="top")

num_variables_entry = tk.Entry(root, justify='center')
num_variables_entry.pack(side="top")

add_constraint_button = tk.Button(root, text="Ingresar Número de Variables", command=lambda: create_entries())
add_constraint_button.pack(side="top")

obj_coefficients = []
constraint_frame = None
cons_coefficients = []
constraint_variables = []
constraint_types = []
cons_values = []
num_constraints = 0
num_variables = 0

def create_entries():
    global num_variables
    num_variables = int(num_variables_entry.get())
    tk.Label(root, text="Función Objetivo").pack()
    for i in range(num_variables):
        obj_coefficients.append(tk.Entry(root, justify='center'))
        obj_coefficients[i].pack()

    tk.Button(root, text="Agregar Restricción", command=add_constraint).pack()
    tk.Button(root, text="Resolver", command=solve_lp_problem).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Así se ingresan los datos solo los numero sin las variables x1 y x2
Cada ves que se le de click a agregar restricción sera un restricción nueva
Luego de añadir todos los datos se le da resolver.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A mi me da el error "Valuerror: Invalid literal for Fraction 'z = 15x1 + 10x2'" (creo que es porque he ingresado la ecuación de manera diferente a la que está programada). ¿Podrías añadir una captura con los datos que hay que ingresar en cada Entry por favor?. También podrías ayudar indicando en que parte del código se encuentra el error, son 160 líneas y probablemente hagan falta cambiar 5~10

Comment: @DanielSánchez Claro ya subo como se ingresan los datos

Comment: @DanielSánchez También puedes ingresar los datos en decimales con puntos ejemplo 6.5  y no 6,5 o enteros